# How to preg_match all the digits and not the url coded commar

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

I the following URL `https://test.example.com/blah/12345%2C80%2C8263473%2C9475834343`
After the `https://test.example.com/blah/`part of the URL, there are numbers being separated by `%2C`. I want to get an array of all the numbers in the URL. The number may a positive 1 all the way up to positive infinity. There may be an infinite amount of numbers in the URL or nothing at all (in this case the array is empty).

In this scenario, I want an array like:
`[12345, 80, 8263473, 9475834343]`

```
$url = "https://test.example.com/blah/12345%2C80%2C8263473%2C9475834343";

preg_match('/\b\d+\b/', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

However, the only element in my array is `12345`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also make use of the `\G` anchor to get those numbers:

```
(?:https?://\S+?/blah/|\G(?!^))(?:%2C)?\K\d+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `https?://\S+?/blah/` Match the protocol and till the first occurrence of `/blah/`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?:%2C)?` Optionally match `%2C`
- `\K\d+` Forget what is matched so far, and match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNSZEC/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/YdKBU)

Example

```
$re = '`(?:https?://\S+?/blah/|\G(?!^))(?:%2C)?\K\d+`m';
$str = 'https://test.example.com/blah/12345%2C80%2C8263473%2C9475834343';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => 80
    [2] => 8263473
    [3] => 9475834343
)
```

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov I have added a PHP demo to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider just splitting on encoded characters, to generate an array of the numbers you want

```php
$url = "https://test.example.com/blah/12345%2C80%2C8263473%2C9475834343";
$url = preg_replace("/^.*\//", "", $url);
$matches = preg_split("/%\w{2}/", $url);
print_r($matches);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => 80
    [2] => 8263473
    [3] => 9475834343
)
```

Comment: The thing is, that I don't want the `2`. You are getting the `2` from `%2C` which is the separator. If you decode `%2C` in terms of a URL, it is a comma

Comment: @Zoey I have tried to salvage my answer.  Maybe what you want here is a regex split on any `%` encoded character.

Comment: Can this not be done with pure `preg_match_all`? If not, can we do `$url = url_decode($url)` then use `preg_match_all`

Comment: The separators are the encoded characters, making a split a logical way of doing this.  We could probably use `preg_match_all`, but it seemed more error prone to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this would work with PhP in a working environment but would either of the following be an option to you?

```
%2C|(?!.*\/)(\d+)
```

Where you'd first match the "%2C" part and use an alternation to match groups of digits after your last forward slash to grab those groups of digits in an array. Again, I'd not be sure how you'd get an array from that 1st capture group.

If something like that would fail, maybe exclude the "%2C" part from your final array with backtracking control verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` like so:

```
%2C(*SKIP)(*F)|(?!.*\/)\d+
```

A possible alternative way of writing this could be:

```
(?:^.*\/|%2C)(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+
```

Comment: I think the last one without the lookahead would be more efficient to prevent the lookahead from firing on every position where `%2C` does not match.

Comment: @Thefourthbird; thank you for the response and rightfull point on efficiency! I had no idea if it would work (I don't know PHP) but I looked at your PHP demo; swapped the patterns and it seemed to have worked fine =)

Answer (score 1):

Another one solution:

```
$url = "https://test.example.com/blah/12345%2C80%2C8263473%2C9475834343";

$decodedUrl = urldecode($url); // convert url to .../blah/12345,80
$queryListString = substr($decodedUrl, strrpos($decodedUrl, "/") + 1); // get string after last slash
$intList = explode(',', $queryListString); // convert string to array by comma
```

This code is very simple, so you could use it. First of all you need to make `urldecode`, which convert to regular string. after that make another manipulations.